# Trying to parse webpage using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, web-crawler

I am trying to parse a webpage and print out a table which is on the webpage. I am using php_simple_html dom parser. However, when I try to parse the table off the webpage, all the javascript commands to output the table get turned into comments within the php:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<?php
    include 'crawling/simple_html_dom.php';
    $html = file_get_html('http://uiucfreefood.com/');


    $ret = $html->find('body', 0)->find('div', 10)->find('table',0); //gets to the table tag
    echo $ret; // nothing is echoed out because the original webpage uses jscript commands to write the table to the page but these commands get turned to comments for some reason.
?>
</html>
```

When I inspect the element of the page where I am echoing the parsed information I am able to see that the table tag with all the info is in there but the jscript commands have been turned into comments. Is there a way for me to just grab the info and echo it out myself? I tried adding another ->find('tbody'); at the end of the parse command but it doesn't do anything. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: You can try this code out yourself if you download the simple_html_dom.php and include it in your php file. Source: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

EDIT: Just noticed something really important. The javascript commands are commented out in the original webpage also. Instead, the original webpage is using a javascript function to print out the table which I do not have defined. Writing that function myself should fix the issue.

EDIT: yup, that worked.

Comment: Why do you care about the Javascript commands in the first place? Edit: ahh, I see, hmm

Comment: to be honest, I don't if there is a way for me to grab the info. I thought just keeping the jscript commands in there would be an easy way to just output the table as is.

For example, I would just like every row of the table, such as:
"lunch 11/12
12:00 428 Armory Building Integrating Undergrad Research in Large Introductory Classes"

Comment: Yeah, not sure how to do that without actually running the Javascript

Comment: You may have to download page with ajax using a request object to spoof the website to generate the content. I know that you have to do this with Python's  `BeautifulSoup` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using file_get_content instead of get HTML and see if that works. Honestly, depending on your needs, you should code your own parser. It is not that hard to write a parser for the table scan and display.

You will just need the following;

```
$array = split("<table>", $content);
$boolPlaceHolder = false;
```

and you can then set the placeholder to true when you encounter  this way you can scan through the chars of the content and grab the table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ended up doing this, turned out to be way easier.